# React Native Download multiple JSON and combine

Tags: json, react-native, fetch

I am trying to download multiple JSON and combine them together in the variable and display them in a flatlist. But I am only seeing contents from only 1 JSON. How do we do multiple download and combine the result ? Is there a better way to do this ? Am I downloading it the correct way ?

```
export default class CategoryScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            dataSource: [],
            AllNews: [],
        }
    }
  
    componentDidMount(){
        this.GrabData('http://hunterdata.serveblog.net/t-computerworld.json');
        this.GrabData('http://hunterdata.serveblog.net/t-thestar.json');
    }

    
    async GrabData(TheURL) {
      let tmpData = [];
      try{
        const response = await fetch(TheURL, {headers: {'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache'}});
        const data = await response.json();
        tmpData = data;
        if ((this.state.dataSource.length) = 0) {
          this.setState({ dataSource: tmpData });
        } else {
          let tmpData1 = this.state.dataSource;
          tmpData = [...tmpData1, ...data];
          this.setState({ isLoading: false, dataSource: tmpData})
        }        
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
        

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <ActivityIndicator />
                </View>
            )
        } else {

          let mydata = this.state.dataSource;
            return (       
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
              data={mydata}
              renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.text}>{item.title}</Text>}
              />
            </View>            
            );
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if ((this.state.dataSource.length) = 0) {`

Should be

`if ((this.state.dataSource.length) === 0) {`

Answer (score 0):

You are so right. Thank you. This solved my issue.

if ((this.state.dataSource.length) === 0) {